# Why doesn't a vector resize move its contents? Can I force it to?

Tags: c++, vector, move, c++17

When the capacity of an `::std::vector<T>` is reached and an additional element is inserted, it appears that `::std::vector<T>` **copy-constructs** the data after reallocating a larger portion of memory.

This seems horribly inefficient if for instance we have a `vector<vector<vector<int>>>` because the entire content must be deep-copied. If **move semantics** were exploited the overhead would (typically) be constant per entry, as opposed to unbounded.

### Question(s)

1. Why does it do this?
2. Can I force it to `::std::move` the contents?

---

### Example

To analyse this, I implemented a small wrapper type `DataPrinter` that holds a `char` and basically `cout`s each construction/destruction. And I get this:

```
::std::vector<DataPrinter> v;
::std::cout << "emplacing a\n";
v.emplace_back('a');
::std::cout << "emplacing b\n";
v.emplace_back('b');
::std::cout << "emplacing c\n";
v.emplace_back('c');

emplacing a
[0x60200000eff0] DataPrinter(a)
emplacing b
[0x60200000efd1] DataPrinter(b)
[0x60200000efd0] DataPrinter(DataPrinter[a]const &)
[0x60200000eff0] ~DataPrinter[a]()
emplacing c
[0x60200000efb2] DataPrinter(c)
[0x60200000efb0] DataPrinter(DataPrinter[a]const &)
[0x60200000efb1] DataPrinter(DataPrinter[b]const &)
[0x60200000efd0] ~DataPrinter[a]()
[0x60200000efd1] ~DataPrinter[b]()
```

I am building with `clang++ 3.5.0-10` and `-fsanitize=address -std=c++1z`.

Comment: does `DataPrinter` have a `noexcept` move constructor ?

Comment: Ah, no it isn't `noexcept` but it has a move constructor. Checking ...

Comment: Yes, that was it. If I add `noexcept` to all ctors it moves content. Thanks. Do you have an explanation why `noexcept` changes this? (-> answer?)

Comment: Because the reallocation isn't allowed to throw.

Comment: @GillBates: But the const-ref copy-ctor wasn't `noexcept` either. So it's basically the same, isn't it?

Comment: @bitmask It's just the move constructor which is not allowed to throw.

Comment: @LogicStuff Yep, that's a dupe. Couldn't find it with the search before I asked. Voted to close.

Comment: @bitmask it goes like this, if a copy-construction throws an exception, the original vector is unchanged (good). if a relocation fails in the middle due to a move construction failure of a single element, then the original vector is already modified. to restore its original state, you'd have to reverse the operation by move constructing the elements back, which can again throw (bad), see [`std::move_if_noexcept`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move_if_noexcept) for a reference. that's why a copy-constructor is allowed to throw

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki That actually makes a whole lot of sense, thank you for the explanation!